# How to define a custom validator for each column in Handsontable

Tags: javascript, validation, spreadsheet, handsontable

The example [here](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.33.0/demo-data-validation.html) perfectly explains how to define custom validators for Handsontable.

Example:

```
(function(Handsontable){
    function customValidator(query, callback) {
        // ...your custom logic of the validator

        callback(/* Pass `true` or `false` based on your logic */);
    }

    // Register an alias
    Handsontable.validators.registerValidator('my.custom', customValidator);

})(Handsontable);
```

From now on, you can use `customValidator` like so:

```
var hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('container'), {
  data: someData,
  columns: [
    {
      validator: 'my.custom'
    }
  ]
});
```

Since this validator validates data of each column. **But I just want to validate one column only**.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the more advanced examples on the [link](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.33.0/demo-data-validation.html) you have shared this may answer your question.

But it will depend completely on what structure your data is in and the names of the columns.

I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwcbcfcj/1/) of their second example on the page and added the custom validator.

From this you can see that they are referencing specific columns by name:

```
columns: [
    { data: 'id', type: 'numeric'},
    { data: 'name.first'},
    { data: 'name.last'},
    { data: 'ip', validator: ipValidatorRegexp, allowInvalid: true},
    { data: 'email', validator: emailValidator, allowInvalid: false}
]
```

So you can call the custom validator as such:

```
columns: [
    {
        validator: 'my.custom',
        data: 'columnName'
    }
]
```